# Update repo error

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I have this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
daniele@daniele-XPS-13-9343:~$
```

when I type `sudo apt-get update`. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/sources.list` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

You have Ubuntu 12.10 that is not supported any more.

I suggest installing Ubuntu 14.04. It will be supported till April '19.